# How to save DOM together with attached events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, event-handling

I'm up to complete jQuery/ajax - based UI, and I have a little problem: I need to save all nodes below `<div id="mainpanel">` but to retain events attached with them, so I could to interact with this previous DOM.

Let's say this DOM:

```
<div id="mainpanel">
    <a href="#" id='firstopt'>First option</a>
    <a href="#" id='secopt'>Second option</a>
</div>
```

I have click handlers both with #firstopt and #secopt. If I click one of them, in next step I want to be able to go back and to have exactly the same DOM above. 
Part of that I'm able to achieve by simply saving current DOM I want to be able to go back to:

```
var currentDom=$('#mainpanel').html();
```

and restoring when I need it:

```
$("#mainpanel").html(currentDom);
```

now after step above, I have first DOM, but without every single event that was attached to nodes below.
How to save them as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .detach() function from jQuery and store the return value:

```
var elements = $(".someSelector").detach();
```

And then re-add them:

```
$(".container").append(elements);
```

This should keep all jquery related events attached to it.

[Detach API](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of serializing the DOM to HTML (a process in which you will loose event handler bindings), just keep a reference to the node(s):

```
var currentDom = $('#mainpanel').children();
$("#mainpanel").empty().append(currentDom);
```

Also have a look at [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) for removing the children from the container.

---

Depending on the overall context, instead of keeping a reference to DOM elements and their event handlers, [*event delegation*](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be I misunderstood. But I think when you try to use this DOM elements again, It will have a duplicate id. So you can not handle any event again. I think you should use class instead of ID.

```
<div id="mainpanel">
    <a href="#" id='firstopt' class='yourClass'>First option</a>
    <a href="#" id='secopt' class='yourClass'>Second option</a>
</div>
```

Now you can handle with class above!